# Can't echo $session->flash(); in CakePHP 1.3.4 - Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('gotcha!!', 'msg_success');
```

to write a msg in the Session and try to access it in the file

\app\views\elements\msg_success.ctp

with the code

```
if($session->check('Message.flash'))
{
    echo $session->flash();
}
```

My Phpinfo() says

> memory_limit    512M    512M

My app/config/core.php says

```
Configure::write('Session.save', 'php');
Configure::write('Session.cookie', 'CAKEPHP');
Configure::write('Session.start', true);
```

how can that be???

Comment: CakePHP is heavy, but I believe that this error is not from the session. Try to see if you don't have model recursion more than 2 somewhere.

Comment: no recursion at all. Without the flashoutput the site works fine. still have no clue whats wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Session Component and the Session Helper set in the controller.  They are not on by default.  Although, I would assume it would throw an error, not eat up your memory.

Also, you shouldn't need to do `if($session->check('Message.flash'))` before using `$this->Session->flash()`.  It should degrade gracefully if no flash message has been set.

Answer (score 0):

in your `msg_success.ctp`, try just using

```
<?= $message; ?>
```